# error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'

Tags: c#, casting

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
int dd= 6000;
sqlCmdDefaultTime = new SqlCommand("myQuery", sqlCon);
sqlDefaultTime = sqlCmdDefaultTime.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlDefaultTime.Read())
{
      dd= sqlDefaultTime[1];
}
```

how can i cast

Comment: the error is in the line `dd= sqlDefaultTime[1];`

Comment: Further reading: [Unboxing Conversion (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b95fkada(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple cast to `int`:

```
dd = (int)sqlDefaultTime[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
int.TryParse(sqlDefaultTime[1].ToString(), out dd);
```

in the event that the parse is successful `dd` will now be a new value.

Unless of course the object is an int already, the you can just cast it...

```
dd = (int)sqlDefaultTime[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the indexer try to use the GetXXX methods of SqlDataReader:

```
dd = sqlDefaultTime.GetInt32(1);
```

More GetXXX methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt();

a few others such as TryParse and TryParseExact provide more functionality and control.

```
dd= Integer.parseInt(sqlDefaultTime[1]);
```

should do it, provided you can guarantee the value being returned is always an int.