# Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, ms-word, msdn

i am trying to create table of contents in a word document, but i keep getting this error:
"Error  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
            object style = "Heading 1";
            Word.Range rng = style;
            oDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(rng);
```

I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm a beginner.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Word.Range rng = (Word.Range) style;
```

Would solve the issue, an object type needs explicit type cast to a specific type.

Comment: Though I have answered this question, most people will not like the  idea of asking such a question, if you are learning please do google search and it will give you correct answer in the first link itself like the one below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894984/error-cs0266-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-object-to-int

Comment: In c#, this is only called unboxing if the target type of the cast is a value type.  In this case, the target type is not a value type.

Comment: @phoog agreed, but still type casting is required for the reference types too

Comment: Of course.  It's just called something else.  I'd also note that adding a cast here will fix the compiler error, but the code will raisean InvalidCastException at run time.

Comment: @phoog agreed again, that would qualify for a runtime exception question from the user :)

Comment: Of course, again!  I have to say I am somewhat sympathetic to the question, though, remembering how long it took me, when I first switched to C# from VB, to deal with the fact that you can't (for example) do things like `string s = "5"; int i = s;` or even `int i = (int)s;`.